# Supporting iOS 7 with iOS 8 compatible app that includes extensions

Tags: ios, xcode

I have built an app for iOS 8 using the Today widget extension. I was wondering how to make sure that people with iOS 7 could still download and use the app.

Do I make the Today widget development target iOS 8 but the actual app development target iOS 7?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're on the right track: The app needs to be built with the iOS 8 SDK and can have an earlier deployment target. The widget's deployment target is iOS 8, and it will be ignored on iOS 7 devices. You can easily verify that in the simulator, too.

If you share code between the widget and the app, this code needs to work in iOS 7 and 8, obviously. Specifically, if you use frameworks to share code between your app and the widget (which is [recommended by Apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/ExtensionScenarios.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014214-CH21-SW1)), you should read [this document](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/ExtensionScenarios.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014214-CH21-SW3). However, it seems to be easier to just not use (own, embedded) frameworks as long as you target iOS 7.

Answer (score 0):

1. Check the OS version and make a fallback behavior for

   NSString *osVersion = [[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion];
2. Check if you have access to the functions you wish to use:

   [YourClass respondsToSelector:@selector(yourDesiredFunction)]

Apple’s SDK Compatibility Guide:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/developertools/conceptual/cross_development/Introduction/Introduction.html

Comment: I found out that #2 was just making the framework optional, but I am still confused on the today widget. How do I make a fallback behavior for an entirely separate target?

Comment: In first options is better to use comparing with NSFoundationVersionNumber_iOS_7_1

Answer (score 0):

hagi is right, but we have tried to run apps with frameworks on ios7 and it worked. But the best way is with weak linking and check.

It is a bad scenario, because in our frameworks is nearly all non-UI code: model, parser and loading.